# how to get previous value in angular typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used `typeahead` in input element. On change, I can get the current value from `$item` by using `typeahead-on-select`. How to get the previous value?

I have tried `ng-click` to set the old value

```
<input type="text"
    ng-model="personDetail.brandchainname"
    typeahead-on-select="redeReferenceId($item, $model, $label, personDetail.id, oldValue)"
    ng-click="oldValue = personDetail.brandchainname"
    typeahead="data as data.name for data in brandChainNames | filter:$viewValue"
    typeahead-editable= 'false'>
```

However, in a `typeahead`, you can change the value by backspacing as well and this time the old value will be still from `ng-click`.

Comment: 1st place why you want oldvalue?

Comment: Have to de-reference `personDetail.id` from previous value and re-reference into new one.

Comment: I tried using 
`typeahead-on-select="redeReferenceId($item, $model, $label, personDetail.id, oldValue, clicked)"
                        ng-click="oldValue = personDetail.brandchainname; clicked=true;"`


and then in controller, 

`$scope.redeReferenceId = function(...){
      $scope.clicked = false;
}`


It seems this scope is not the same as passed.

Comment: could you please create a fiddle/plunkr with what so ever you have tried..

Comment: It would be difficult to create one. However, I resolved the issue by making `clicked` an object. <br/>
`ng-click="oldValue = personDetail.brandchainname; clicked = {'value': true};"`<br/>
which then I set in controller as clicked.value = false; This helped me differentiating the clicked event and backspace event. From there onwards, I solved the issue of prev value by using an array saving prev and curr value.

Comment: @pankajparkar, There is one issue with `typeahead` though. It does not fire `typeahead-on-select`, when you remove the value from input field completely and that is still a problem in my case.

Comment: Sorry to say..but I can't predict what is going on..for that I'll need code with the reproducible proble.

Comment: Well, I solved the last problem by using ng-blur. 

`ng-blur = "util.isEmpty(personDetail.brandchainname) ? redeReferenceId($item, $model, $label, personDetail.id, oldValue, clicked, 'brandchainnames') : ''"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use $scope.watch for getting new and old value

```
 $scope.$watch('field', function (newVal, oldVal) {
   // your task
}
```

Comment: That gives me all sorts of values in `oldval/newVal` viz. `""`, `undefined` etc. That fires, when you type partially before actually selecting a value. Coding for that is proving very difficult and buggy.

Comment: pahle wahi try kiya tha..thodi complexity ke baad bhi, expected result nahi mila